# APEX ORACLE OAUTH2

Tags: oracle, oauth-2.0, apex

I have a problem geting token in pl\sql in postman it works fine but in pl/sql I get error

```
client_id varchar(255) := 'client_id,';
client_sec varchar(255) := 'client_sec';
endpoint varchar(255) := 'http://localhost:3000/ords/restw/oauth/token';
begin

    apex_web_service.oauth_authenticate(
                p_token_url =>     endpoint,
                p_client_id =>     client_id,
                p_client_secret => client_sec
            );

end;
```

ORA-20987: Error at line 1, col 1: strict mode JSON parser does not allow unquoted literals
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_JSON", line 401
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_JSON", line 736
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_JSON", line 762
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_JSON", line 1222
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 612
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_WEBSERVICES_API", line 501
ORA-06512: at line 7
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Comment: Are you sure the 3 parameters that you are using are valid? Are you able to successfully get a token using a tool like Postman?

Comment: Yes I am in Postman working just fine with that 3 parameters that I use.